# SQL change query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Executing the below query is giving me error.

I'm trying to re-name a column name.

```
alter table student change dateofbirth dob;
```

the above query is giving error

> incorrect syntax change

I'm using SQL Server 2016

Comment: please check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 you will find the answer to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sp_rename` to rename a column: [Rename Columns (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

For what you have, it appears you're after:

```
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.student.dateofbirth', N'dob', N'COLUMN';
```

I'm not sure where that syntax you got is from. `CHANGE` is not a SQL Server keyword; perhaps you were looking at the wrong RDBMS' documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you cannot use the `alter table` syntax to rename a column. You can use [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) instead:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'student .dateofbirth', 'dob', 'COLUMN';
```